# Queue entry to url in Flask

Tags: web-services, websocket, flask

I'm trying to do the following thing

People go in my site, they press a button, and connect to the server via WebSocket to send some data (takes a while). If another client connects to the site and presses the button while another client is already sending data through the WebSocket, I want the second client to be redirected to another page that says its position on the queue for the websocket.

When the first client finishes the transfer, the next one in line will connect to it. So basically I'm trying to get a server resource to be used by only one client at a time (with a queue for others to wait in).

Is there a way to make something like this work?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you can have only one WebSocket connection at a time? Even if you only want only one client to transmit data at a time, notifying the next client in line sounds like a perfect use case for WebSocket (server pushing state info to a client).

Comment: I ended up doing exactly that. thanks!